# Loess preprocessing for robust quadratic regression?

Tags: least-squares, loess

It seems to me that we could fit a quadratic curve to the predictions of a LOESS curve in order to obtain a parametric model approximating the non-parametric LOESS model.  Is this something that is done to perform robust quadratic regression?  Are there any texts that describe such a preprocessing step?

Specifically, the steps would be, fit a LOESS curve to $X$, $\mathbb{y}$.  Obtain predictions $\mathbb{\hat{y}}$ from the LOESS smoother evaluated at the training set $X$.  Fit a quadratic regression on $X$, $\mathbb{\hat{y}}$.  For bandwidths approaching 0, the resulting quadratic would approach the un-preprocessed quadratic regression.  For bandwidths approaching $\infty$, the resulting quadratic would approach a line (at least within the range of the training data).  Thus, this seems like a valid way to make a "robust" quadratic regression.

Is this process or something like it examined in any literature/textbooks?

Comment: Why not use one of the many well-understood robust regression procedures on the data directly?

Comment: My interest is mostly in the theoretical properties of the LOESS estimator.  It occurred to me that something like the above would be straightforward to construct, and that the "polynomial-approximatability" (whatever that means) of LOESS curves might be studied somewhere.  I am surprised that I haven't found anything after searching all day, since such a thing doesn't seem *utterly* unreasonable...